# Grab public IP address using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, ip

My current IP is : `24.62.137.161`

and when I use

`$ip = $request->getClientIp();
dd($ip);`

I keep getting `::1`

How can I grab `24.62.137.161` ?
I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do if possible.

Any hints / suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: ::1 is IPv6 version of 127.0.0.1, so I'm guessing you are calling yourself. I don't know which OS you are using, but maybe you should have a look at doing requests with eth0 instead of lo?

Edit: since you want your external address, probably you will have to use some loopback. Right now, can't really thing of a solution, except maybe, bootup a couple vm's, change their ip address and do the requests between them?

Comment: try this and see what you get as result  `print_r($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`

Comment: Are you running a local (development) server and trying to get your own IP address by accessing it?

Comment: @Bogdan : I don't want to grab the ip of my localhost. I want to grab the IP of the user that view my site. Basically, I want to grab my user ip address. I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: @Bolovsky: I'm not that good with VM. I'm a noob. I just want to grab my user ip address when they register my site. I just want to get the rough idea of where they are at in the world.

Comment: @ihue this should work perfectly in a publicly reachable server. if you just want to get a feel for it, you can go to laravel entry script (don't know if you changed any default, probably should be app.php or something like that) and override $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to the ip you want. Keep in mind this is a hack for you to be able to test it. To get you own IP will take you a lot of reading hours and effort

Comment: @Bogdan : I got it now, thank-you for commenting on my post. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$ip = trim(shell_exec("dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"));
```

---

```
dd("Public IP: ".$ip); //"Public IP: 24.62.137.161"
```

Comment: Ahh,, thanks much. this is what I was looking from 2 days

Comment: Great answer , saved my day !!! , can you please explain what this command do  `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` ?

Comment: @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol Can someone suggest how to the client Ip address in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

try this to Grab public IP address using Laravel,

```
Request::getClientIp()
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried that already. I keep getting `::1`. Thanks for suggesting. :-)

Comment: when i fire ifconfig on client I am getting actual public IP of client, and when I request to my laravel server from the client and logging the ip using Request::getClientIp() then I am getting different IP of the client.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This

```
$ip_address = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org');
print_r($ip_address);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is the expected result when you are in `local` environment (development mode). But when the app is running in `production`, you will get the public IP address that you want.

Summary base on your question:

- In local: `127.0.0.1`
- In production: `24.62.137.161`

Answer (score -2):

You can get the exact IP with the following function
gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`))