# How to check from which site user came to my site?

Tags: laravel, url, routes

I need to check if user went to certain routes from my site or from other site and execute  logic that depends on site user came from. I tried to do something like this

```
if( redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl() === '***') {

}
```

but it returns http://localhost:8080 instead of real site I went to localhost from

Comment: As in your want to get the previous url the user visited?

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you combined that solution of yours(the one giving your localhost url) and with the tracking of the client's(public) IP address? For more you may follow the following discussions:

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896017/laravel-get-website-unique-visitor-count?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268683/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-laravel-5)
3. [Link 3](https://www.edureka.co/community/65056/how-to-get-user-s-ip-address-in-laravel)
4. [Link 4](https://www.expertsphp.com/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-laravel-5-8-with-example/)
5. [Link 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128924/grab-public-ip-address-using-laravel)
6. [Link 6](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-client-ip-address?page=1)